# Migrating from .live to .on when using functions and selector

Tags: jquery

Probably a simple answer but I don't understand the principles of jQuery enough to work it out.

I have this:

```
$(".remove", document.getElementById(itemsAreaId)).live("click", function(){
```

which I want to migrate to `.on()`

I tried doing this

```
var selectedEls = $(".remove", document.getElementById(itemsAreaId));
   $(document).on('click',selectedEls, function(e){
```

But it doesn't work.

Anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

And if possible why my solution didn't work so I can understand.

many thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optional selector for `on()` [must be a string](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You're providing it a jQuery object (`selectedEls`).

Instead, simply use the string selector `.remove` directly. Rather than targeting `document`, use `itemsAreaId`;

```
$('#' + itemsAreaId).on('click', '.remove', function ());
```

If you wanted to target `document`, you could use the descendant selector along with `itemsAreaId` and `.remove`, like this;

```
$(document).on('click', '#' + itemsAreaId + ' .remove', function ());
```

... but it's better to attach handlers as close to the source as possible, so the first would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful.  And obvious now you explain it :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document.getElementById(itemsAreaId)).on('click', '.remove', function(e){}
```

**Explanation**:

As you know, jQuery can accept a string or even a DOM Element as a constructor for its object, so `$(document.getElementById(itemsAreaId))` will give you the fastest and closest access to your element.
`.on('click', '.remove', function(e) {}`
This one will call the function(e) when any element with the class `remove` inside your element with `itemsAreaId`(which `on` function is attached to) is clicked.

Using `$(document)` will cause your event to be checked every time the user clicks; the same way using `$('#' + itemsAreaId)` will be slower(we're talking about milliseconds) because jQuery will have to parse the string to retrieve the DOM element.